# Get list of styles in React Testing Library

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-testing-library

I want to check for styling of all selected `span` elements:

```
<div class='color selected'>
  <span/>
</div>
```

I tried it like this:

```
const selectedColorNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.color.selected');
const selectedColors = Array.from(selectedColorNodes).map(
      (item: HTMLElement) => item.firstElementChild.style.backgroundColor,
    );
expect(selectedColors).toBe(['ffffff', '000000', '7d533f']);
```

But `selectedColors` always is `['','','']`

`style` is highlighted as well with error: `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure because you didn't attach the classes css styling but I can see you are accessing `firstElementChild` which in the example you provided is a `span` with no classes. I **assume** that this span doesn't have any styling but on the page it looks like it has the background color you are trying to assert while in fact it's the parent element who is styled with that color so what you get is empty strings because there is no background color on the child element itself.

Generally it is not recommended to write tests for styling but if you find yourself doing that a lot, I would recommend adding [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) which has many useful assertions like `toHaveClass` or `toHaveStyle` which would make your tests more concise and more readable.